# transform data set in R from stacked months and years for multiple sites to sites with columns of year-month

Tags: r, time-series, transformation

I have a dataset of monthly averages from multiple (250) stations over several years (1980-2023). These data are currently stacked with a monthly average for each month of each year for each station. How can i transform them so that there are 250 rows with 516 columns (43 years x 12 months) that include the months with no data as NA?

[image: current data set from averageing by year and month]

```
2   110453  2023    11  370.9           2023-11
93  110453  2023    12  415.1788    2023-12
94  110453  2024    1   676.5803    2024-1
95  110453  2024    2   673.1603    2024-2
240 123548  2019    1   683.2573    2019-1
241 123548  2019    2   683.1791    2019-2
242 123548  2019    3   684.3534    2019-3
243 123548  2019    4   689.1183    2019-4
244 123548  2019    5   688.6553    2019-5
245 123548  2019    6   685.6333    2019-6
```

I have tried:

```
monthly_averages_1980$year_month <- paste(monthly_averages_1980$Year, monthly_averages_1980$Month, sep = "-")
monthly_averages_1980 <- spread(monthly_averages_1980, key = year_month, value = Average_Value)
```

but it doesn't remove the excessive rows from the input dataframe.

[image: spread results exmaple]

it also sorts the coulmns as alpha (1980-1, 1980-10, 1980-11...).

i'd like something like this:

[image: desired format]

Comment: This seems like a standard long to wide transformation: `tidyr::pivot_wider(monthly_averages_1980, id_cols=station, values_from=Average_Value, names_from=yearmonth)`

Comment: The problem here is you have redundant time columns: `year`&`month`, as well as the column combining them like "2023-11." You need to remove the `year`&`month` columns before pivoting, otherwise the values from different months will remain in different rows.

Comment: elegant, jon. thanks